# Mewebstudio Purifier add custom attribute?

Tags: laravel, attributes

Using: https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier
And I can't add any custom attribute.
Tested all possible variations and still nothing.
In the config file I see this:

```
'custom_attributes' => [
        ['a', 'target', 'Enum#_blank,_self,_target,_top'],
],
```

But after testing `<a target="_top" href="www.example.com">Example.com</a>`
nothing happens.

Did I miss something?

I just need two attributes with custom text inside :

```
data-rel
data-title
```

Please someone help or suggest better alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration file you should add following:

```
'custom_attributes' => [
            ['a', 'target', 'Enum#_blank,_self,_target,_top'],
            ['img', 'data-rel', 'Text'],
            ['img', 'data-title', 'Text'],
        ],
```

Note that this is valid only for img tag. If you want to have those attributes for another tag you can change the first array element accordingly.

Then in default configuration array you should actually allow those custom attributes like this:

```
'default' => [
            'HTML.Doctype'             => 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional',
            'HTML.Allowed'             => 'img[width|height|alt|src|class|data-rel|data-title],table,tbody,tr,td[style|rowspan],h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,small,div,b,strong,i,em,u,a[href|title|target],ul,ol,li,p[style|class],br,span[style],sup,sub',
            'CSS.AllowedProperties'    => 'font,font-size,font-weight,font-style,font-family,text-decoration,padding-left,color,background-color,text-align,vertical-align',
            'AutoFormat.AutoParagraph' => false,
            'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty'   => false,
        ],
```

Note the added data-rel, data-title attributes in HTML.Allowed string near the img element.
Again, if you want custom attributes for another tag you should specify it in both custom_attributes array and HTML.Allowed string.